# Similar smell for avocado and raspberries

Tags: olfaction

I noticed when heating frozen avocado that the smell was just like fresh raspberries in the summer. Does anyone know what makes them smell so similar ?

(https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-408117-8.00029-5)

"One-half an avocado is a nutrient and phytochemical dense food consisting of the following: dietary fiber (4.6 g), total sugar (0.2 g), potassium (345 mg), sodium (5.5 mg), magnesium (19.5 mg), vitamin A (5.0 μg RAE), vitamin C (6.0 mg), vitamin E (1.3 mg), vitamin K1 (14 μg), folate (60 mg), vitamin B-6 (0.2 mg), niacin (1.3 mg), pantothenic acid (1.0 mg), riboflavin (0.1 mg), choline (10 mg), lutein/zeaxanthin (185 μg), cryptoxanthin (18.5 μg), phytosterols (57 mg), and high-monounsaturated fatty acids (6.7 g) and 114 kcals or 1.7 kcal/g (after adjusting for insoluble dietary fiber)"  ("Hass Avocado Composition and Potential Health Effects", Mark L. Dreher and Adrienne J. Davenport)

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/food-science/avocado

$
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{Compound} & \text{Raspberry} & \text{Avocado} \\ 
\hline
   \text{provitamin A/$\beta$-carotene} & & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin A} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin B} & \checkmark &  \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin $B_1$/thiamine-HCl} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin $B_2$/vitamin $G$/riboflavin} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin $B_3$/vitamin $PP$/niacin} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin $B_5$/pantothenic acid} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin $B_6$/pyridoxine} & & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin C/ascorbic acid} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin D/calciferols} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin E/$\alpha$-tocopherol} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin $H$/biotin}  &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{vitamin K_1/phytyl menaquinone} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{acid:citric acid} & & \checkmark  \\
\hline
   \text{acid:folic acid} & \checkmark &  \\
\hline
   \text{acid:malic acid} & & \checkmark  \\
\hline
   \text{acid:oxalic acid} & & \checkmark  \\
\hline
   \text{$\alpha$-carotene} & & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{anthocyanins} & \checkmark &  \\
\hline
   \text{choline} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{cyanidin-3-glucoside} & \checkmark & \\
\hline
   \text{anthocyanin was cyanidin-3-rutinoside} & \checkmark & \\
\hline
   \text{cryptoxanthin} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{dietary fiber} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{ellagitannins} & \checkmark &  \\
\hline
   \text{folacin} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{folate} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{high-monounsaturated fatty acid} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{phospholipids} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{glycolipids} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{free fatty acids} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{lutein/zeaxanthin} & & \checkmark  \\
\hline
   \text{persenone A} & & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{persenone B} & & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{phytosterols} & & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{$\beta$-sitosterol} & & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{sugar} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{B (boron)} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{Ca (calcium)} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{Fe (iron)} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{K (potassium)} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
  \text{Mg (magnesium)} & & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{Na (sodium)} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{P (phosphorus)} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
   \text{Zn (zinc)} &  & \checkmark \\
\hline
\text{2(R)-(12Z, 15Z)-2-hydroxy-}\\\text{4-oxoheneicosa-12,15-dien-1-yl acetate} & &\checkmark\\
\hline
\end{array}
$

$
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
   \text{sugar} & \text{Raspberry} & \text{Avocado} \\
\hline
   \text{glucose} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{fructose} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{d-Manno-heptulose} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{perseitol} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{sucrose} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
\end{array}
$

$
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
   \text{neutral lipid} & \text{Raspberry} & \text{Avocado} \\
\hline
   \text{monoacylglycerols} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{diacylglycerols} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{triacylglycerols} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
\end{array}
$

$
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
   \text{neutral lipid:triacylglycerol} & \text{Raspberry} & \text{Avocado} \\
\hline
   \text{dioleyl palmitin} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{triolein} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{dioleypalmitolein} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{linoleyl oleyl palmitin} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
   \text{linoleyl diolein} & & \checkmark\\
\hline
\end{array}
$

Seems there are hundreds of volatile compounds for raspberries, so will not list them all here (unless I find a matching volatile compound, then I might update this question).

What I found matching http://dx.doi.org/10.1590/1678-457X.01316 and doi:10.3390/molecules20022445:

```
(E)-3-Hexen-1-ol    Green, grass, leafy odor; bitter, grassy-fatty notes
1-octanol   Grassy, plastic, solvent
2-butanol   Oily, wine-like, fusel-alcoholic note
2-ethyl furan   Strong, sweet-ethereal, burnt brown musty odor
2-decanone  Orange-like, floral odor
2-hexanone  Fruity, ketonic, banana, yeasty, cheese, dairy notes
2-phenyl ethanol    Rose, perfumery
3-methyl-3-buten-1-ol   Fruity, green
4-methyl-1-pentanol Oily green-fruity, herbaceous,
acetophenone    Sweet, pungent, harsh
benzaldehyde    Almond, fruity, powdery, nutty
benzyl acetate  Sweet, floral, fruity odor of jasmin and gardenia, fruity taste
benzyl alcohol  Faint, sweet, fruity aroma; sweet taste
ethyl acetate   Ethereal, sharp, wine-brandy like odor
hexanal Oily, avocado
limonene    herbal, sweet
linalool    Sweet floral
naphthalene Musty taste
nonanal Fatty-floral-rose, waxy odor
octanal Fatty-fruity odor; sweet, citrusorange-fatty taste
p-cymene    Strong, characteristic, terpene odor
pentanal    Strong, acrid, pungent odor; chocolate
α-copaene   Woody, spicy, sweet
α−terpineol Sweet, floral (lilac), lime odor;
β-pinene    Sweet, lemon
γ-nonalactone   Strong, fatty, coconut
```

Comment: Attempt enhancing the quality of your question and, firstly of your research

Comment: @Algae — The question is clear (despite being flagged as otherwise) and the poster has done some research which he believes will help someone provide an answer. I personally regard his question as uninteresting, and regard him as naive in thinking that any common nutrient in his lists is likely to be responsible for his (subjective) observation. He would be better advised to search specifically for the biology of odorants, but I don't think your comment is particularly fair or helpful.

Comment: Since listing nutrients was discouraged I will stop now ...

Comment: @Emil Although I do not know the answer to your question, I disagree with David & think that this is exactly how biochemists identify tastes & smells. Impossible food wanted a meat-free burger so they put beef into a chromatography-mass spectrometry machine, which identifies specific molecules. Among other things, they detected butter, syrup, and used diapers. Before advanced mass-spec, quantifying the smell was a challenge that has been going on since the 1800s. [Here is a paper](https://tinyurl.com/t8rz48o) from 1963 suggesting one method to quantify the smell by using many people.

Comment: I have ordered a book called Smellosophy now, hopefully I will get a better understanding of the psychology after reading that one.